# DataGridView avoiding adding new columns

Tags: c#, datagridview

Why, this code create 2 the same columns in grid (Color and Color). How to inputs data color from collection in column which existing before set datasource ??

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ds = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            ds.Name = "Color";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(ds);

            List<Car>  cars=new List<Car>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Car car=new Car {Type = "type" + i.ToString(),Color=Color.Silver};
                cars.Add(car);

            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = cars;


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set  `AutoGenerateColumns=false` before setting the DataSource.

#### Take 2:

set  `AutoGenerateColumns=true` and find the column afterward:

```
 var ds = dataGridView1.Columns["Color"] as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn;
```

That is, if you want it - your code does not really use the column so you might as well remove al the code for creating it.

Comment: It doesn't works...variables from cars dont fall in predefined columns

Answer (score 0):

You statically add a "Color" column. Then you set a List as the data source of the grid. You have a "Color" property defined in the Car class. This property is reflected and displayed as a column too.